# ImportError: No module named packaging.version

Tags: python-import

When I tried installing Flask I got this error:

```
ImportError: No module named packaging.version
```

Answer (score 15):

To fix this, I had to do:

```
pip install setuptools
```

Comment: Thanks man. That worked like a charm, after wasting about an hour Googling for the error. :)

Answer (score 13):

If your Python runs on Ubuntu, try to do this:

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
mv pkg_resources/ pkg_resources_bak/
```

I'm not sure what package installed the "pkg_resources", it will make pip always show error.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
```

Comment: I was having the above-mentioned error on my raspberry pi model B. If anyone else comes here with my problem, this answer fixed it for me.

Comment: I encountered this error on macOS after upgrading to High Sierra and re-installing MacPorts. Nothing worked until I tried this.

Answer (score 4):

As an Ubuntu 14.04 user, [upgrading pip to version 9.0.1](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py) fixed this problem for me.

### Upgrading pip normally

- Download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) script
- Run: `python get-pip.py`

### Upgrading/installing pip behind a corporate firewall

- Download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) script, along with [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip), [wheel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel), and [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) from pypi
- Place all files in the `/tmp` directory
- Run the following command to install pip: `sudo -H python /tmp/get-pip.py --no-index --find-links=/tmp pip`

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone stumbles upon this problem, my solution was to change the packaging version from 22.0 to 21.3.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I was getting the same error in 21.3 too. But I installed 23.1 and it worked.